# Insert NIC driver into custom install.wim

Tags: windows, deployment

Up to today, I have been using a single boot.wim file and a single install.wim file (captured from a configured PC, with DISM) to install Windows 10 from my Server 2012R2 WDS server. Now we have purchased new hardware and I need to add a driver to both .wim files. I was able to use the following steps to put the driver into the boot.wim:

1. Dism.exe /mount-wim /wimfile:d:\temp\boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:d:\temp\mount
2. Dism.exe /image:"d:\temp\mount" /add-driver /driver:"d:\temp\drivers\IntelI354"

Once that was done, I PXE booted and was able to pull down my install image. So, I used the same steps to update install.wim, but when I pulled down the updated image, the NIC was not detected.

I followed the steps in scenario 1, from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd348456%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, to deploy driver packages through WDS, but it obviously didn't work.

What do I need to do, to get this new NIC driver properly installed in my image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/doxley/2007/12/13/editing-the-registry-of-your-wim-without-having-to-recapture/ to load the registry file from the WIM, and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753716(v=ws.11).aspx to add my desired directory to the DevicePath registry entry.